# Is there a way to see the value behind a raw pointer in strace output?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, strace

With strace it is possible to see the ioctl call for the certain file descriptor and with certain command. The third argument is a structure, but strace shows it as a raw pointer to the memory. 
strace output example:

```
open("/dev/node", O_RDWR) = 3
ioctl(3, 0x108, 0x8f0eb18) = 0
close(3)
```

Is there a way (strace options or other tools) to see what is the structure, or at least a value behind a raw pointer?

Comment: Does it give you the address of the instruction? If so it's really simple in GDB to add a break point and then look at the memory... How you'd determine the actual structure I'm not so sure.

Comment: I mean that if I would write it in my program, it would look like this:
`ioctl( dev_node, IOCTL_CODE, &ioctl_struct )`, where third argument is a structure of type Ioctl_Buf_Struct. When strace is used for the binary program as we see in the example above, I would be curious to know what is behind 0x8f0eb18 address: what is the structure that is sent there, or at least what is it's value. Can gdb help here?

Comment: well... If you run the program, stop if just before that command, then you can find the values by dereferencing the pointer. Use strace to find all the malloc calls, until you find the one that returns that pointer. That will tell you the size of the struct. You can then look at the memory, with the known size, and so reproduce the struct in it's binary form. You may never know *what* the struct is, but you can find the value.

Answer (score 2):

In gdb, if you stop it right before the call to ioctl, you can then enter:

```
(gdb) p *(ioctl_struct *) 0x8f0eb18
```

That will show you how the contents of that memory location maps to the ioctl_struct.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar problem: wanted to inspect a syscall to `ioctl` made by `vde_switch` (which creates a TUN/TAP virtual network interface), in order to know what I was doing wrong in my code (which had to do the same thing as `vde_switch`, but programmatically.)

By running:

```
sudo strace vde_switch -tap tap0
```

I was able to know, as Terry Greentail, that the syscall being made was `ioctl(5, TUNSETIFF, 0x7fffa99404e0)` and the pointer would be a reference to a structure of type `struct ifreq`. In my code I had something like `ioctl(tapfd, TUNSETIFF, &ifr_dev)`.

Initially I tried to make gdb stop on a syscall, setting: `catch syscall ioctl` (I had run gdb as `gdb --args vde_switch -tap tap0`), but whenever the catch was hit, gdb showed no information about the parameters of `ioctl`. After struggling with this for a while, I decided to run strace inside gdb, as:

```
gdb --args strace vde_witch -tap -tap0
```

Although no breakpoint had worked in this way, the output showed which file descriptor was being used:

```
open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)            = 9
ioctl(9, TUNSETIFF, 0x7fffffffe350)     = 0
```

So I tried another time with: `gdb --args strace vde_witch -tap -tap0` and set a conditional breakpoint:

```
b ioctl if $rdi==9
```

The calling convention (I'm on an AMD64) uses `RDI` for the first parameter, `RSI` for the second and `RDX` for the third (see [System V AMD64 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI).) Finally, when the breakpoint was hit, I was able to inspect the `ifreq` structure:

```
Breakpoint 6, ioctl () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: File or directory not found.

(gdb) p (struct ifreq) *$rdx
$5 = {ifr_ifrn = {ifrn_name = "tap0", '\000' <repete 11 vezes>}, ifr_ifru = {ifru_addr = {sa_family = 4098, sa_data = '\000' <repete 13 vezes>}, ifru_dstaddr = {sa_family = 4098, sa_data = '\000' <repete 13 vezes>}, ifru_broadaddr = {sa_family = 4098, sa_data = '\000' <repete 13 vezes>}, ifru_netmask = {sa_family = 4098, sa_data = '\000' <repete 13 vezes>}, ifru_hwaddr = {sa_family = 4098, sa_data = '\000' <repete 13 vezes>}, ifru_flags = 4098, ifru_ivalue = 4098, ifru_mtu = 4098, ifru_map = {mem_start = 4098, mem_end = 0, base_addr = 0, irq = 0 '\000', dma = 0 '\000', port = 0 '\000'}, ifru_slave = "\002\020", '\000' <repete 13 vezes>, ifru_newname = "\002\020", '\000' <repete 13 vezes>, ifru_data = 0x1002 <Address 0x1002 out of bounds>}}
```